# How can I write a wirechark dissector where the format of the packet depends upon a field in the packet?

Tags: wireshark, wireshark-dissector

I am writing a Wireshark dissector for a custom protocol. The protocol is as follows:  The first 3 bits of the packet defines how the rest of the packet is constructed. For example, if these 3 bits are 00, the remainder of the packet is a 6-bit field followed by 2 byte fields. If the leading 3 bit is 01, the remainder of the packet is a 14-bit field followed by a byte field. I have successfully dissected the leading 2-bit field (which I've called hf_format). In the dissector function, My code does this at the moment:

```
proto_tree_add_item( ..hf_format...);
if(hf_format==0)
{
   proto_tree_add_item( ..6-bit field...);
   proto_tree_add_item( ..first byte field...);
   proto_tree_add_item( ..second byte field...); 
}
else if (hf_format==1)
{
   proto_tree_add_item( ..14-bit field...);
   proto_tree_add_item( ..byte field...);
}
else  etc.
```

Wireshark correctly shows hf_format in the dissected packet, but the other fields are not dissected.
Can you tell me what my error is?  I have searched the web extensively and read every document I can find, including the official documentation, but haven't found anything enlightening on the matter.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Writing a Non-trivial Wireshark Dissector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61129327/writing-a-non-trivial-wireshark-dissector)

Comment: Please refrain from asking *the exact same question* multiple times on the same day. Duplicate above.

Comment: I thought the previous question was closed because the moderator said it was too vague.

Answer (score 0):

*The first 3 bits of the packet defines how the rest of the packet is constructed.*
I assume this is a typo and you meant ***The first 2 bits ...***?

Somewhere before/after `proto_tree_add_item( ..hf_format...);`, you have to actually read at least the 1st byte from the tvb so you can test the 2 relevant upper bits of that byte.  Perhaps you are doing that, but it's not shown in the pseudo-code provided.  For example:

```
guint8 format = (tvb_get_guint8(tvb, 1) & 0xc0) >> 6;
proto_tree_add_item( ..hf_format...);
if(format==0)
{
   proto_tree_add_item( ..6-bit field...);
   proto_tree_add_item( ..first byte field...);
   proto_tree_add_item( ..second byte field...); 
}
else if (format==1)
{
   proto_tree_add_item( ..14-bit field...);
   proto_tree_add_item( ..byte field...);
}
else  etc.
```

The [Wireshark Developer's Guide](https://www.wireshark.org/docs/wsdg_html_chunked/ChapterDissection.html) provides some additional help here, but it refers you to the [doc/README.dissector](https://code.wireshark.org/review/gitweb?p=wireshark.git;a=blob;f=doc/README.dissector;h=7887b45ac6742de4ec919eafa86d011e871e4e98;hb=HEAD) file for even more information, and that would be my recommendation as well.  There are other useful README's as well, such as [doc/README.developer](https://code.wireshark.org/review/gitweb?p=wireshark.git;a=blob;f=doc/README.developer;h=bf15d68c4f99b7e29460ae781b85b89c94cbeb81;hb=HEAD), etc.

Comment: Yes, I made a mistake when I edited the question.  And, yes, I am reading the byte that has the field in question.  I will look at the references you give more closely, in case I missed something when I read them before.  Thanks for your feedback.